# Why are some AutomationPeer are sealed?

Tags: c#, datagrid, automated-tests, ui-automation, flaui

I have a DataGrid where an additional parameter exists at a DataGridRow. I want to test this parameter with FlaUi. I have already read up a bit on AutomationPeers. As far as I understand you have to create a new AutomationPeer and make the parameter available there.  My problem is that the DataGridRowAutomationPeer is seald and I can't derive from it. Does anyone know why MS did this? And is there possibly a simpler variant?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: No idea why that is the case. I guess you need to copy the original one (they are usually only a few dozen lines, this one as well) and very seldom change.

Comment: The problem is that I can't just copy the code of the class because it refers to methods that are internal. So I am dependent on the fact that I can derive the class.